# get row id given a button in a cell DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a DOM-created table whose cells were created with a loop that stored information from a JSON object with buttons at the end of each row that I would like to use to delete a row. All of my rows have unique id's and my plan is to pass the row id into a function on button click so I can delete the row in my database as well as on my page.

However, I can't figure out how to get the id of the row with the button alone.

Comment: Could you include your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using something like .innerHTML or adding an element so that you can write all the code, including the button. When you write the button, put in onlick `onclick=deleteFunction(idOfRow)` where you would write the ID of the row in idOfRow. Then just use that to know which row to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using jQuery, the below will return the row element of the particular button you clicked on if you pass in the button id, replace 'domElementId' with your button id.

```
$('#domElementId').closest('tr');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are in the row that's to be deleted, then you can use the DOM structure to identify the row without using an ID. From the button, you can use an *upTo* function that ascends the DOM from a given root until it reaches an element with a particular tag name:

Then from the button you can pass *this* to the function so it goes up the DOM to a TR node, then deletes it. E.g.

```js
/* Starting from a node, ascend the DOM until the first parentNode 
** with a particular tagName is encountered.
** @param {DOMElement} node - node to start from
** @param {string} tagName  - tag name of node to return
** @returns {DOMElement/null/undefined}
**          - If matching element is found, returns the node.
**          - If no match found, returns null
**          - If either parameter not provided, returns undefined
*/
function upTo(node, tagName) {
  if (!node || !tagName) return;
  tagName = ('' + tagName).toLowerCase();
  while ((node = node.parentNode) && node.tagName) {
    if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return node;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function deleteRow(node) {
  var row = upTo(node, 'tr');
  if (row) row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>row 0
  <tr><td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>row 1
  <tr><td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>row 2
</table>
```